# Change font color of selective email addresses in outlook compose window

Tags: outlook, outlook-addin

I am writing a outlook 2010 add-in using VSTO and C#. From my add-in's code I want to change the color of certain email addresses in outlook's compose window.
The attached screen shot demonstrates what I want to achieve.
[image: change outlook email color]

Is this possible and if so what kind of approach should I take? even if it is possible by some setting or macro it should help me look in the right direction.

Thanks.
Deepak.

Answer (score 0):

There is no publicly available API to do that.